# No navigation after using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, cakephp

I'm using this to show a loading image before I load 3 pages.The code is working and shows the loading image before going to these pages from anywhere else then these 3 pages.
 The problem is when I go to these pages and form there I click on one of the 3 pages' links, it doesn't do anything. Just adds a # to the end of the url.

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
                    });

                    //Loading Image.
                    var ajax_load = "<img src='http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/412_ajaxCalls/DEMO/img/load.gif' alt='loading...' style='top:48%; left:48%; position:relative;'/>";

                    //PHP file URL.
                    var loadUrl = "/cakephp/Posts/index";
                    var loadUrl2 = "/cakephp/Posts/fetchHome";
                    var loadUrl3 = "/cakephp/accounts/getFollowers";

                    //$.get()  
                    $("#dash").click(function(){  
                        $(".container-fluid2").html(ajax_load);  
                        $.get(  
                        loadUrl,  
                        {language: "php", version: 5},  
                        function(responseText){  
                            $(".container-fluid2").html(responseText);
                            history.replaceState(null, "Dashboard", "posts");
                        },  
                        "html"  
                    );  
                    });  
                    $("#home").click(function(){  
                        $(".container-fluid2").html(ajax_load);  
                        $.get(  
                        loadUrl2,
                        {language: "php", version: 5},  
                        function(responseText){  
                            $(".container-fluid2").html(responseText);
                            history.replaceState(null, "Timeline", "posts/fetchHome");
                        },  
                        "html"  
                    );  
                    });  
                    $("#followers").click(function(){  
                        $(".container-fluid2").html(ajax_load);  
                        $.get(  
                        loadUrl3,  
                        {language: "php", version: 5},  
                        function(responseText){  
                            $(".container-fluid2").html(responseText);  
                            history.replaceState(null, "View followers", "accounts/getFollowers");
                        },  
                        "html"  
                    );  
                    });
```

Comment: Did you understand the code well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! This is how it should be to re-load the javascript functions again and again:

```
$(document).on("click", "#dash", function(){ 
                            $(".container-fluid2").html(ajax_load);  
                            $.get(  
                            loadUrl,  
                            {language: "php", version: 5},  
                            function(responseText){  
                                $(".container-fluid2").html(responseText);
                                $("#CancelReply").hide();
                                history.replaceState(null, "Dashboard", "/cakephp/posts");
                                $(document).attr('title','Dashboard');
                            },  
                            "html"  
                        ); 
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it all worked after I added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //your code here
}
```

The document.ready handler waits until the page is loaded before running. This is important because previously you may have been trying to add an event handler to an object that doesn't exist yet.

Hope this helps.

If not get back to me and i'll have another look.

Comment: Open up developer console or firebug and paste any error messages